# M2Crypto error Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, m2crypto

I am a windows7 64-bit user working with Python 3.4.

I installed M2Crypto library. I followed the steps mentioned in this link for installing M2Crypto on Windows: https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/blob/master/INSTALL

I have Microsot Visual Studeio 2013 community edition installed. I also have Visual c++ 2008, 2010, 2012 redistributable for bith x86 and x64.

I have the MinGW and Swigwin installed in the C: directory.

when I try to install M2Crypto using this command from the Python34/Scripts:

```
pip install m2crypto
```

I get errors as the following:

```
> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install m2crypto Collecting m2crypto   Using
> cached M2Crypto-0.22.3.tar.gz Installing collected packages: m2crypto 
> Running setup.py install for m2crypto
>     Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
> okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\e\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-sxa0uziu\\m2cryp
> to\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
> open)(__file__).read().repl ace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))"
> install --record C:\Users\e\AppData\Local
> \Temp\pip-ad2ukv1d-record\install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed  --compile:
```

then it copies a list of files. At thie end I get this:

```
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find
> vcvarsall.bat).
```

followed by this:

```
> Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='C:\\Us
> ers\\e\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-sxa0uziu\\m2crypto\\setup.py';exec(compi
> le(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n'), __fil e__, 'exec'))" install --record
> C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ad2ukv1d-recor d\install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-sxa0uziu\m2crypto
```

Please, help me fix the issue. I could not find a resource that describe the steps properly.

Comment: you'd need to download visual studio express . It is freely available.

Comment: @poke sorry, this is not a duplicate question. The previous one was general before I try the VC++. Somebody suggested a link which I have tried but did not work. Now, I have specific error message after trying the previous link. Plz, remove the mark of duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run pip install from a command prompt with both the needed python programms and visual studio in the search path. (`PATH`)

Open a Visual C++ command prompt and note the result of

```
echo %PATH%
```

and add the relevant visual c++ / visual studio directories to your python command prompt similar to this

set PATH=C:\path\to\VS;%PATH%